# What would be the most proper way to send email?

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I'm learning TypeOrm and i'm trying to implement an email verification system after a user creates an account.

Let's say i have two entities, User and EmailVerification. When the user is created, an EmailVerification related to this user is inserted in the database. The next step would be to send an email to this user right after the EmailVerification is created.

But i'm not sure about what typeOrm feature to use to call my email service send function.

I was thinking of two ways to achieve this,

1 - From the transaction as a complementary step after inserting user and emailVericiation in database :

```
await getManager().transaction(async entityManager => {

  await entityManager.save(user);
  await entityManager.save(emailVerification);

  // send the message directly from the transaction right after the user and emailVerification is created
  await emailService.send(message);

})
```

2 - From an EntitySubscriber right after the creation of the EmailEntity :

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class EmailVerificationSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<EmailVerification> {
  @AfterInsert()
  sendEmail() {
    // ... //
    // get related user email
    // ... //
    
    // then send the message
    await emailService.send(message);
  }
}
```

These two ways seems sufficient to me, but i would like to know if there is some kind of best practice for this use case ?

I can provide more informations if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter very much which option you choose.

That being said, the email you send is part of a workflow that starts when you insert your `emailVerification` object. So it makes sense to associate it with that operation.

If you use a similar workflow in future for password recovery, it will become obvious why that makes sense.